# Yii2 ActiveQuery use OR in Link array

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii2

I want to use OR operator in `$link` array in `hasMany`  function in class extended by ActiceRecord. 
For example, I want to get transactions which related whith user account. In sql it would be something like `SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE fromAccountId = :id OR toAccountId = :id` But how I can wrote this using Yii2

```
    public function getTransactions() {
        return $this->hasMany(Transaction::className(), [
            'fromAccountId' => 'id',
            'toAccountId' => 'id'
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Link ActiveQuery works with the keys of the array as name column, values - as value of column.

> The array keys must be columns of the table for this relation, and the array values must be the corresponding columns from the primary table

Because the code doesn't work (`where (fromAccountId, toAccountId) IN ('id','id')`):

```
[
    'fromAccountId' => 'id',
    'toAccountId' => 'id'
]
```

You can rewrite hasMany behavior in getTransactions()

```
public function getTransactions() {
    $query = Transaction::find();
    $query->multiple = true;
    return $query->where(['OR',
        ['fromAccountId' => $this->id],
        ['toAccountId' => $this->id]
    ]);
}
```

**It supports native behavior, as expected:**

```
$model->getTransactions() // return as \yii\db\ActiveQuery
$model->transactions // return as array of Transactions models
```

**But doesn't work for `$model->find()->with('transactions')`**, because `with` require setting `$query->link`. Instead `with` need to use `join....`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the find(), it's not as nice, but do the work:

```
return $this->find()->join('LEFT JOIN', 'transaction', 'fromAccountId = id OR toAccountId = id')->all();
```

Maybe you have to use tablename.id!

Answer (score -2):

I have not tried this, but you could try something like

```
public function getTransactions() {
        return $this->hasMany(Transaction::className(), ['1' => '1'])->where('fromAccountId = id OR toAccountId = id');
    }
```

The idea is to create a join without a condition (or with a dummy condition) then use where to get the actual results you want. This might mean a massive performance problem.

Comment: ['1' => '1'] Getting unknown property: Model::1

Comment: Getting unknown property : Model ::1